# How do I secure the top of my vinyl siding?

Tags: vinyl-siding

The top panel of my vinyl sliding keeps popping off every few months.  I can pop it back in, but it inevitably falls out again.

[image: Image of siding]

What is the right way to secure it?

Comment: Pictures.  How is it secured now and what is popping off, the bottom or top edge?

Comment: vertical siding is held by j-channel at top and bottom - shouldn't be able to slip out.

Comment: @crip659 Picture added

Comment: The whole panel is falling down.  It seems like the bottom edge is where it gets loose.  You may be able to see that the bottom edge of the top piece that is still attached is not very secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top piece of vinyl siding is supposed to have tabs pressed into it from a snaplock punch.  This is what allows the top edge of the vinyl to be locked into place inside a utility, finishing, or sill trim.  Mine was installed without these tabs, but had some nail holes, so I assume whoever installed it attempted to nail it in place, which worked until the nails fell out.  Once I made these tabs, I was not able to pull the top siding out without using a removal tool.  It only took about 10 minutes.

[This](https://www.renovation-headquarters.com/siding-vinyl-installation-5.html) is a good resource on the tabs and trim, specifically Figures 15-18.  As is [this video](https://youtu.be/BJzl7MbY5OU?si=6ue35d9tqno8pog_).